# Inconsistent etags behavior in v3 search API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, etag

Search API v3 with `maxResults` 1 always returns same `etag` and hence works as expected. Request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<KEY>&part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=HUMAN%20BO&safeSearch=strict&type=video`,

but `maxResults` >1 returns `etag`s from a set of `etag` pool and seems like its not working as expected. Request:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<KEY>&part=snippet&maxResults=2&q=HUMAN%20BO&safeSearch=strict&type=video`.

I have verified the response by asking for all the fields and response wise there is no change.
How does the `etag` computation is done on v3 search API side?

[image]

Is this a bug or something internally used to compute `etag`s on YouTube API that results in this behavior? Without much clarity on the docs it's difficult to understand the behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. Important thing: please obey to SO guidelines: [do not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8327971), but ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) plain text.